Расположение элементов пагинации в слайдере
Пытаюсь реализовать слайдер такого плана.

Хочу использовать для этого Slider Swiper.
Подскажите пожалуйста:

Можно ли добиться такого расположения элементов пагинации в виде полукруга исполльзуя Slider Swiper?
Как просчитать правильно чтобы элементы расположились именно таким образом, в виде полукруга?
Какой тип Slider Swiper для этого использовать? Я остановился на типе Thumbs gallery loop

Очень буду благодарен за разъяснение.

Статически думаю можно, а вот анимация будет хромать, так как не заточена под это. Лучше делать свою реализацию

Тоже ищю инфу. Есть идея, но пока не знаю как реализовать.. Нижние круги сделать из пагинации, а основной коментарий с фото уже через сам слайдер

Этот вопрос похож на: Слайдер с отзывами. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1594189/264178
